# Unsupported devices in Play Developer Console

Tags: android, permissions, console, manifest

I am having problems with unsupported devices in my Beta release.

As a temporary solution I have a lot of images inside the app. This resulted in a big apk size, so I opted into splitting it into multiple apk files for different densities.

Now I have a apk for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi and all for small, normal, large and xlarge displays. API level 15+.

Play Developer Console lists 11869/13866 devices as compatible. Uncompatible devices include my development device Nexus 6p and also Nexus 6, 5X and Nexus 7(2012).

Play Developer Console lists permission and features as follows:
Features:

```
android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
```

Permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
applicado.layette.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

What could be the reason for these devices to be listed as unsupported? Opening the apps page in browser did not give any more info, as some tutorials suggested it would. Is there any way to analyze this further?

Comment: Something very similar happens to me in API 19+. I'm getting incompatibilities due to this error message 'safe: "19 and above versions". Any clues¿?